# touchmove event fires onload unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm using touchmove like:

`document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("touchmove",alert("touch"),false);` after the device ready event

in chrome and cordova , but it acts strange, in cordova fires at the beginning unexpectedly(like onload event) and in chrome, it's never fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const callback = () => { alert("touch") }
document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("touchmove", callback  ,false);
```

I think because you call alert inside the addEventListener, get triggered immediately when parsed. This way, you allow the event listener to trigger it.

Comment: In a nutshell whenever you have `()` it triggers the function like `alert()` instead of `alert. Cordova is a bit different than chrome when it comes to parse the code, so i assume it triggers the function when it parses rather than only when the listener is triggered. It was a bit of a stab in the dark. Also this used yto happen in older versions of IE where you had to create the callback separately and then pass it inside the listener.